# Python Django strangely does mapping towards unexpected URL

Tags: python, django

I tested 1st Django web app project.
That app project redirects to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/` when the URL of `http://127.0.0.1:8000` is visited. The test was successful.

And then, I tested 2nd Django web app project.
That Django app should have redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/` when the URL of `http://127.0.0.1:8000` is visited but Django strangely redirects to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/` which was target URL of 1st Django web app.

There is no `/api/` URL configuration in 2nd project
Following code snippets are URL configuration of 2nd Django web app

```
# AskDjango_webfrontend_begin/askdjango/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # If the client enters in "localholst:8000", the page is redirected to localholst:8000/blog/
    path("", RedirectView.as_view(url="/blog/", permanent=True)),

    # If the client enters in "localholst:8000/blog/", connect to blog.urls.py
    path("blog/", include("blog.urls")),
]
```

```
# AskDjango_webfrontend_begin/blog/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.index,name="index"),
    path('<int:pk>', views.post_detail, name="post_detail")
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser has cached the `302 Redirect` HTTP response from the first URL. Clear your cache and try again.

I recommend you to use different hostnames (such as `127.0.0.1` and `127.0.0.2`) while testing multiple web applications running on the same development PC.

Comment: Thanks. Using different `ALLOWED_HOSTS` value from `AskDjango_webfrontend_begin/askdjango/settings.py` file, for example, `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.2"]` worked